# Oauth Account linking issue - "something went wrong, so I couldn't sign you in"

Tags: actions-on-google

I finished the OAuth Account Linking.
I can log in successfully before.

But now, It did not (for both Google Console Test and Google Assistant used by Gmail Account),
it always informs me that
"Sorry, something went wrong, so I couldn't sign you in. But you can try again later."

[image]

Steps :

- 'Talk to NCT'
- 'login' to call Sign In action
- 'yes' to begin sign in OAuth
- it opens browser to login OAuth
- I login account, then redirect success back
- "Sorry, something went wrong, ..."

I make sure :

- the OAuth server worked, since it worked for Amazon Alex application,
- OAuth server does not change anything, ex. : clientId, clientSecret, ...
- Webhook server (nodejs code) did not change codes related to google actions sdk, or Sign In codes line.

People who knows,

Please give me more ideas about this issue,

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got mistake,
the secret key was changed,

I must typed correct secret key at Google Console => Develop

DONE.

Comment: it's working also on google home device or not.

Comment: Worked for both.

Comment: @HuyTower: Can you please provide me the guide for account linking. I try to implement account linking with oauth & google signin

Comment: @Ramesh S : https://medium.com/voice-tech-podcast/account-linking-in-actions-on-google-a0775e44a7cc